# Discord.JS how would I add a text based user input parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code for a command called `ping` looks like this:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),

    options: [
        {
            name: 'message',
            description: 'Replies with your message!',
            type: 'string',
            required: false,
            default: 'Pong!'
        }
    ],
    async execute(interaction, args) {
        const [ message ] = args;
        return interaction.reply(ping);
    },
};
```

And currently, when I run this command (and deploy the slash commands first), there is no user enterable parameter, and it throws an [error](https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/petufelibe.css).

Comment: What is `args` defined as?

Comment: I don't know actually, I put it there because I thought that is how you parse the arguments 

Comment: Log `args` and see what it is, seems like it's not a string array

Comment: alright, will try that now

Comment: it's undefined - I just want to know how to access that parameter - or even set one in the first place

Comment: Pass it into your command handler. You most likely have `command.execute(interaction)`, add `args` as a second parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ik i answering too late, but you can create variable and use it to get content from the input:

```
const message = interaction.options.getString('message')
```

`getString('message')`
instead of the message inside brackets you can put whatever the name of the option or command is.

for example:

```
.addStringOption(option =>
            option 
                .setName('off')
                .setDescription('anti-spam is off')
        )
```

now i need to get this 'off' inside option, so easy,

```
const SpamOn = interaction.options.getString('off')
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access that parameter in a slash command, the user must be able to enter a parameter, so when you register the command, you must indicate how many parameters you want to receive and what type.

Documentation on how to add parameters to the commands [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#option-types).

Documentation on how to read the arguments of a user-entered command here enter link description [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#parsing-options).